# Ajax post action call passing multiple model to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model

I'm working on asp.net mvc web application. I have a form that is used to register information about users. The save action is written on button click. And I'm trying to pass multiple model to the controller. But in controller it is getting null.How do i solve this problem..i have tried some solutions.

Here is my example - pls check:

I have a parent model:

```
public class ParentUsers
    {
        public Login loginModel { get; set; }
        public Details registerModel { get; set; }
    }
```

Jquery function

```
$("#registerLE").click(function () {          
            var form = $("#registration");
            var validatable = form.kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

            debugger
            if (validatable.validate()==true) {                
                var parentModel = {
                     loginModel :{
                        Username: $('input[name=uname]').val(),
                        Password: $('input[name=password]').val(),
                        Role: 'LE'                       
                    },

                 registerModel: {
                    name: $('input[name=firstname]').val(),
                    userId:1  
                  }

                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/Register",
                    data: { "parentModel": parentModel },
                    datatype: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("You Multiple Data Passed Successfully");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert('No Valid Data');
                    } 
                });
            } 
        });
```

Controller method :

```
 public ActionResult Register(ParentUsers parentModel)
 {
       //...after save..//
       return View("Login");
 }
```

pls help

Comment: Use ajax.begin form, it will a easiest way to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change little bit in your ajax. I have tested your code , its working fine my side

Action Method:

```
    public ActionResult SubmitMethod(ParentUsers parentuser)
    {

        //do stuff here

        return Json( ""  , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Modal:

```
  public class ParentUsers
    {
        public loginModel loginModel { get; set; }
        public Details registerModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class loginModel {

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

    }
```

Ajax Code :

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="btnPost" value="Gel Users" />

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnPost').click(function () {
            alert('btnPost');

            var loginModelObj = {

                Username:"UsernameValue",
                Password:"PasswordValue",
                Role:"RoleValue",
            };

            var registerModelObj = {
                name:"nameValue",
                Id:1

            };

            var SendObject = {

                loginModel: loginModelObj,   //loginModel same name as in Modal
                registerModel: registerModelObj,  //registerModel same name as in Modal
            }


            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Test/SubmitMethod',
                contentType: 'application/json',  // send data type to server
                dataType: 'json',  //return type of data from server
                data:JSON.stringify(SendObject),
                //  asyn: false,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {

                    // do stuff here

                },
                error: function (response, status, xhr) {

                    alert(response.statusText);

                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It Worked ! You saved me ;) (y)

Comment: Glad , it helped you :)